# Use custom tables in spring login form

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building a simple web application utilising the spring framework. I have a login utility, utilising the spring login form. I know the standard table in the database must be called `users` and have fields `username`,`password`, `enabled`. My question is, how do I get spring to go through other table names to look at users credentials to log in. When I change the table name from `users` it doesnt seem to work.

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize default SQL queries using corresponding attributes of **jdbc-user-service**:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="securityDataSource"
          authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from authorities where username = ?"
          users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?"
          />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Just replace table names.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! How come is the user is not in the authority table, it will not work?

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Sorry, let me re phrase it. So I have the users table with the username and password etc, but if I attempt to login without the user being initialised inside the authorities table, the login form will actually not validate. Why is this?

Comment: It will be difficult to help without your security xml.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. :) Thank you though, I had gotten it to work with your answer anyway. Sorry, one last thing I need to mention. So in order for the default Spring login form to work, the three fields 'username','password', and 'enabled' must be within the table? Is that correct? Because I had tried it without the field 'enabled' within the table and it did not work.

Comment: By default yes (because **JdbcDaoImpl** is used under the hood). But you can create and configure your custom **UserDetailsService** (and return enabled = true for all users by default). In this case you are completly free over your DB design (you can use even something differend, say NoSql data store).

Comment: Execllent! This is great, I will definitely have a fiddle around with it shortly. I appreciate your help. Thanks once again.Can I contact you personally if I have any other issues? It seems you really know your way around Spring.

Comment: You are welcome. Post your next question on this site or on the spring forum. No one knows spring better than the community :-)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the advice, will do with my next query